# GNOME crashes repeatedly in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: gnome, crash

GNOME crashes repeteadly with the following error:

```
gnome-shell crashed with signal 5 in _XIOError()
```

I tried to change configurations but it keeps happening. I have just installed GNOME Ubuntu.